# if more than 3 wrong submit, show captcha

Tags: php, captcha

In my sites's login page, users must enter username, password and captcha code correctly if they want to enter user's area. But no one, firstly I, do not like the captcha. And the other hand, you know, web security and spam fact.

So in the first, second and the third time I do not want to show captcha but over 3 wrong submits I want to show it. But I don't have any idea about how to implement this! I tried

```
$_SESSION['wrong_submit'] = 1; 
$_SESSION['wrong_submit']++;
```

Of course not. Please could you help me, how can I do this?

Comment: you tried with session.... then what happened?

Comment: All the time session's value is equal to 1.

Comment: can you share the complete code its difficult to guess or presume anything without the code.

Comment: you have some faults in your logic. `$_SESSION['wrong_submit'] = 1;` guess what this line is doing?

Comment: Did you check variable with `isset($_SESSION['wrong_submit'])` ? Is that variable being kept or deleted and resetted after wrong attempt?

Comment: Try using $_SESSION['wrong_submit'] += 1; which will increment by one (similar to $_SESSION['wrong_submit']++; but it won't reset it back to 1 (Notice, it maybe resetting back to 1 because of $_SESSION['wrong_submit']=1;. After you do so, make sure you also have a $_POST value which triggers if the $_SESSION['wrong_submit'] >= 3 so it will show the capcha.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a column in your users table named `login_attempts`. The column increments on each failed login attempt, and resets on successful login.

The basic structure could be as follows:

```
+-----------+------+------+
|  user_id  |  ip  | date |
+-----------+------+------+
```

To check the number of login attempts, you can use query like below:

```
SELECT count(ip) AS failed_attempts
FROM login_attempts
WHERE ip = $ip
  AND date < (NOW - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Now, in your PHP code, you can check if the value is greater than or equal to 3, and display the captcha if so:

```
if ($data['failed_attempts'] >= 3) {
    // display captcha...
}
```

Comment: Also, do not forget to reset that counter upon successful login.
Otherwise, it would not be "after three failed attempts", but "after three failed attempts in the last 24h".
The situation gets worse considering dynamic IPs

Comment: @nicogawenda: I state that in my answer. "*The column increments on each failed login attempt, and **resets on successful login.***"

Comment: Yub, but the code for that is missing, that's why it's easy to oversee/forget

Comment: @nicogawenda: Yes, I'm just giving some helpful pointers. It should be easy enough for the OP to figure that out. Thanks for pointing it out! +1

Comment: @AmalMurali What if user wrote wrong usernames, so you dont have same username from last time, i think in this situation you have to use different solution.

Answer (score 8):

The whole point of captcha is to prevent robots accessing your site (password cracking etc.).

Sessions use cookies. So to thwart your system all the robot has to do is not send the cookie thereby your server thinking it is the first login attempt and therefore not requiring a captcha. This will enable the robot to try as many times as it likes.

So the answer is yes via sessions but you undermine the whole idea of captcha.

Comment: Showing a CAPTCHA to a user each time they try to log is a great way to annoy them. The usual approach is a delay and possibly showing a CAPTCHA after a few failed attempts.

Comment: @Blender - It is the lesser of two evils. Once they are logged on just enable them to stay permanently or for a long period of time logged on.

Comment: @Blender - If you want to do that then sessions are not the answer. Sessions require client co-operation

Comment: i voted +1 for this answer but seriously, i don't even want those ugly captchas which (forget robots), even humans can't decipher -_-

Comment: very well. Up+. It is best to use captcha like recaptcha 2(invisible) orrecaptcha 3(google)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way....

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION['wrong_pword_count']=0;

    if($stored_password != $provided_password){
        if($_SESSION['wrong_pword_count']<3){
            $_SESSION['wrong_pword_count'] = $_SESSION['wrong_pword_count']+1;
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['wrong_pword_count']=0;

    }

    if($_SESSION['wrong_pword_count']>=3){
        echo "Show captcha here";
    }
```

Comment: The session ID is stored in a cookie. If I never set a `PHPSESSIONID` in my request, my `wrong_pword_count` will always be `0`.

Comment: This code will never reach any value >1. And the name is $_SESSION